# How can i merge two different queries using "Salesforce Object Query Language (SOQL)"?

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-service-cloud

Currently am making two calls to salesforce API to fetch the data, below are the two queries:

```
1>SELECT PermissionSetAssignment.AssigneeId,PermissionSetAssignment.PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment where PermissionSetAssignment.PermissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile=false  order by PermissionSetAssignment.AssigneeId

2>SELECT UserOrGroupId,Group.Name FROM GroupMember  order by UserOrGroupId
```

Can we have a single query instead of two?

Please help Salesforce GURU's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a relation between these tables you can directly fetch the UserOrGroupId in the first query itself

Comment: Thanks Maddy for the update much appreciated. Just wanted to know how could we know if there is any relation between the above mentioned tables (PermissionSetAssignment  and GroupMember)?

Comment: see if there is a lookup field in any of the tables

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between Permission Set Assignment and Group Member. So you have to use two query and you wont be able to do it in one query.